# labeling networkx node attributes outside of nodes

Tags: python, dictionary, label, networkx

I am working on a small example node set belonging to two types `{'human', 'machine'}` and I want to label node attributes in dictionary form outside of each node in `networkx` graph, such as those shown in nodes c, e, j in the graph below. (I used MS Word to add dictionary-type attributes on the graph.):

[image]

The base plot is generated using the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], type = 'machine')
G.add_nodes_from(['h', 'i', 'j'], type = 'human')
G.add_edges_from([('a', 'c'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'd'), ('a', 'f'), ('b', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('b', 'g'), ('c', 'f'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'f'), ('d', 'e'), ('d', 'g'), ('e', 'g'), ('f', 'g'), ('f', 'h'), ('g', 'h'), ('h', 'i'), ('i', 'j')])

def plot_graph(G, weight_name=None):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    plt.figure()
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
    edges = G.edges()
    weights = None

    if weight_name:
        weights = [int(G[u][v][weight_name]) for u,v in edges]
        labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,weight_name)
        nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels)
        nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, edges=edges, width=weights);
    else:
        nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, edges=edges);

plot_graph(G, weight_name=None)
plt.savefig('example.png')
plt.show()
```

But here is the problem,

the `nx.get_node_attributes()` and `nx.draw_networkx_labels()` functions will not include dictionary keys (in this example, 'type') on the labels (this works only for nx.get_edge_attributes() and nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels()), and if one would to use `nx.get_node_attributes()` and `nx.draw_networkx_labels()`, original node names will be replaced by attribute values.

I am wondering if there're alternative methods to label attribute in dictionary format outside each node while keeping node names inside the nodes? How should I modify my current code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The issue of `nx.draw_networkx_labels()` not including keys can be solved by creating a new dict that will hold strings representing whole dicts as values.

```
node_attrs = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'type')
custom_node_attrs = {}
for node, attr in node_attrs.items():
    custom_node_attrs[node] = "{'type': '" + attr + "'}"
```

Regarding drawing node names and attributes, you can use `nx.draw()` to normally draw node names and then `nx.draw_networkx_labels()` to draw attributes -- here you can manually shift attribute positions to be above or below nodes. In the block below `pos` holds node positions and `pos_attrs` holds attribute positions placed above appropriate nodes.

```
pos_nodes = nx.spring_layout(G)
pos_attrs = {}
for node, coords in pos_nodes.items():
    pos_attrs[node] = (coords[0], coords[1] + 0.08)
```

Full example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], type = 'machine')
G.add_nodes_from(['h', 'i', 'j'], type = 'human')
G.add_edges_from([('a', 'c'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'd'), ('a', 'f'), ('b', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('b', 'g'), ('c', 'f'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'f'), ('d', 'e'), ('d', 'g'), ('e', 'g'), ('f', 'g'), ('f', 'h'), ('g', 'h'), ('h', 'i'), ('i', 'j')])

plt.figure()
pos_nodes = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos_nodes, with_labels=True)

pos_attrs = {}
for node, coords in pos_nodes.items():
    pos_attrs[node] = (coords[0], coords[1] + 0.08)

node_attrs = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'type')
custom_node_attrs = {}
for node, attr in node_attrs.items():
    custom_node_attrs[node] = "{'type': '" + attr + "'}"

nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos_attrs, labels=custom_node_attrs)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

A final tip: if you have many edges and your node attributes are hard to read, you can try to set the color of edges to a lighter shade of gray.