# How to use NetworkX's rescale_layout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I am having a hard time understanding how to use NetworkX's [`rescale_layout`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.rescale_layout.html).

The documentation says: `pos (numpy array) – positions to be scaled. Each row is a position` which is not the standard "position dictionary" that the rest of NetworkX uses for plotting. I have tried to use NetworkX's [`to_numpy_array`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.to_numpy_array.html?highlight=to_numpy_array#networkx.convert_matrix.to_numpy_array) on the "pos dict" to no success, and the output of `to_numpy_array` is a `Graph adjacency matrix` which doesn't mesh with the requirement of `rescale_layout`'s `Each position is one row of the array` anyway.

The reason why I am asking is because I have a Network which is generated from some data, which is then moved around by spring_layout, but some of the positions don't generate in a 'nice' manner, so I have implemented a method to manually adjust those positions, which would be easier to do if the network was guaranteed to have positions that always lied within some predefined boundary (e.g. [-10, 10] in the plot). I then need to write the node labels just above the node.

Bonus question: I want to write the label at position (x,y+r) where r is the radius of the drawn node. I have a hacked together way of doing so by taking the square root of the input node size and dividing it by an arbitrary factor. However, I have no idea how the drawn node size is actually determined and each individual graph I make seems to have a different internal scale for each graph, while the drawn node sizes appear to remain the same.

I have trawled through a significant amount of documentation to try to understand the underlying methods, but each layer I peel back only adds more confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a example of your layout:

```
pos = nx.random_layout(G)
```

and it's assigned to a dictionary that looks like:

```
{0: array([0.81931883, 0.8001609 ], dtype=float32), 
 1: array([0.89695644, 0.6070644 ], dtype=float32), 
 2: array([0.89160234, 0.47174907], dtype=float32), 
 3: array([0.20430276, 0.8206253 ], dtype=float32), 
 4: array([0.27929142, 0.08657268], dtype=float32)}
```

Now, since input of `nx.rescale_layout()` should be `numpy` array, you can extract it using a command

```
np.array(list(pos.values()))
```

Note that this way might be [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668509/dictionary-keys-and-values-to-separate-numpy-arrays) on other versions of Python.
I'll give an illustration of what have changed after `pos` parameter is rescaled:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,0]])
pos = nx.random_layout(G)
coords = np.array(list(pos.values()))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplot(211)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, with_labels=True)
plt.axis('on'); plt.tick_params(left=True, bottom=True, labelleft=True, labelbottom=True) #force axis to turn on

plt.subplot(212)
new_pos = nx.rescale_layout(coords)
nx.draw_networkx(G, new_pos, with_labels=True)
plt.axis('on'); plt.tick_params(left=True, bottom=True, labelleft=True, labelbottom=True) #force axis turn on
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So NetworkX doesn't require that pos be a dictionary? Interesting. This actually would allow me to simplify the code significantly since I am manually adjusting the nodes by calling a manually constructed dictionary by the node ID to get a (\delta X, \delta Y) list then adding that like so: pos[node] += manual_adjust[node]. I might keep it that way to avoid rework though. Any idea how you could write text just above each node? I have continued reading, and found people talking about taking the sqrt(marker size)/2, but it is inconsistent to say the least.

Comment: Yeah, this can be an array instead but you need to be careful with indexation of nodes. In my case draws of graph with `new_pos={v:n for v,n in zip(pos.keys(), pos.values())}` and `new_pos={v:n for v,n in zip(range(len(G.nodes())), pos.values())}` might be different if I'll change edges slightly.

Comment: As far as I know, there is now, there is no straightforward way in networkx to draw label text on top of its bounding box. But if you really need it,  disable current labels using `with_labels = False` and use `nx.draw_networkx_labels()` to draw new labels on top of old positions. This is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46503250/3044825

Comment: Thank you for your. I was able to implement a working method in my code like so:

rescale = nx.drawing.layout.rescale_layout
def rescale_graph( pos_dict, scale=1 ) :
    pos_keys = list( pos_dict.keys( ) )
    pos_val = array( list( pos_dict.values( ) ) )
    rescaled = rescale( pos_val, scale=scale )
    pos = { key : rescaled[ i ] for i, key in enumerate( pos_keys ) }
    return pos

This method takes a position dict constructed by other native NetworkX generators, and outputs a rescaled version. I reconstruct the position dictionary so as to not have to significantly rework code.