# networkx rescale_layout returns AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to use the `rescale_layout` method so my graph does not get truncated when saving it as a .png file. The code below however, returns me the error  `AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'shape'`. Any advise?

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge("Node1", "Node2")
color_map = []
for node in G:
    if node == "Node1":
        color_map.append('blue')
    else: 
        color_map.append('green')  

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(272/120, 480/120), dpi=120)
pos = nx.rescale_layout(G, scale=0.2)
```

Here is the error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-a2104b4ce60a> in <module>
      8         color_map.append('green')
      9 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(272/120, 480/120), dpi=120)
---> 10 pos = nx.rescale_layout(G, scale=0.2)

~\anaconda3\envs\ff\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\layout.py in rescale_layout(pos, scale)
   1165     # Find max length over all dimensions
   1166     lim = 0  # max coordinate for all axes
-> 1167     for i in range(pos.shape[1]):
   1168         pos[:, i] -= pos[:, i].mean()
   1169         lim = max(abs(pos[:, i]).max(), lim)

AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63496724/2966723.   The method `rescale_layout`  does not take a graph as input.